# Pandas dataframe to duplicated matrix in sum of quantities

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
data = {0: {'ID': 'A', 'Qty': 1, 'Type': 'SVGA'},
 1: {'ID': 'B', 'Qty': 2, 'Type': 'SVGA'},
 2: {'ID': 'B', 'Qty': 2, 'Type': 'XGA'},
 3: {'ID': 'C', 'Qty': 3, 'Type': 'XGA'},
 4: {'ID': 'D', 'Qty': 4, 'Type': 'XGA'},
 5: {'ID': 'A', 'Qty': 1, 'Type': 'LED'},
 6: {'ID': 'C', 'Qty': 3, 'Type': 'LED'}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
```

Is it possible to transform this dataframe to a duplicated matrix in sum.

Expected output:

```
        LED  SVGA  XGA                
LED       4     1    3
SVGA      1     3    2
XGA       3     2    9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the key here is the "ID" column, because the value for each Type-Type cell is computed with respect to whether these Types coexist for the same ID.

So, start with a self-merge on "ID". You can then pivot your result to get your matrix.

#### `merge` + `crosstab`

```
v = df.merge(df[['ID', 'Type']], on='ID') 
pd.crosstab(v.Type_x, v.Type_y, v.Qty, aggfunc='sum')

Type_y  LED  SVGA  XGA
Type_x                
LED       4     1    3
SVGA      1     3    2
XGA       3     2    9
```

---

#### `merge` + `pivot_table`

```
df.merge(df[['ID', 'Type']], on='ID').pivot_table(
    index='Type_x', columns='Type_y', values='Qty', aggfunc='sum'
)

Type_y  LED  SVGA  XGA
Type_x                
LED       4     1    3
SVGA      1     3    2
XGA       3     2    9
```